# What is the meaning of "the will of my Father" in Matthew 7:21?

Tags: matthew

"Not everyone who says to me, "Lord, Lord," will enter the kingdom of heaven, but the one who does the will of my Father who is in heaven". Matthew 7:21

Matthew 8:31-32 "And the demons begged him,"... "And he said to them, "Go." So they came out and went...".

When Jesus tells demons to go and they obey, has "the will of my Father" been done?

Romans 8:7 "the mind that is set on the flesh is hostile to God, for it does not submit to God's law".

Does that mean that the mind set on the flesh is not subject to "the will of the Father"?

If a demon obeys God is that nothing to do with "the will of my Father" because demons will never enter the kingdom of God?

Are God's purposes for some people not given the accolade of being "the will of my Father"?

["the will of my Father" also in Matthew 12:50 and John 6:40]

Comment: _For I have not spoken of myself; but the Father which sent me, he gave me a commandment, what I should say, and what I should speak. And I know that **his commandment is life everlasting**_ John 10:50 (Up-voted +1.)

Comment: I think you have answered your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Matthew 7:21
English Standard Version

> “Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but the one who **does** the will of my Father who is in heaven.

does
ποιῶν (poiōn)
Verb - **Present** Participle Active - Nominative Masculine Singular

i.e., one who continuously practices in following the will of the Father.

Matthew 8:31-32

> "And the demons begged him,"... "And he said to them, "Go." So they came out and went...".

When Jesus tells demons to go and they obey, has "the will of my Father" been done?

Yes but only on this occasion.

Romans 8:7

> the mind that is set on the flesh is hostile to God, for it does not submit to God's law.

Does that mean that the mind set on the flesh is not subject to "the will of the Father"?

It is not naturally obedient to the will of the Father.

> 12 So then, brothers, we are debtors, not to the flesh, to live according to the flesh. 13For if you live according to the flesh you will die, but if by the **Spirit** you put to death the deeds of the body, you will live. 14 For all who are **led by the Spirit of God are sons of God**.

We don't have to follow the will of the flesh; we can choose to follow the Holy Spirit.

Are God's purposes for some people not given the accolade of being "the will of my Father"?

It's better to look for accolades from God rather than from people.

Comment: You say "We don't have to follow". "We" the church or "we" people in general?

Comment: we as individuals personally responsible to the Holy Spirit :)